# Access inner class variale on outer class

Tags: c++

I want an array in outer class which a variable in inner class is the size of array:

```
struct Outer
{
  struct Inner
  {
    int size{};
    int something_else{};
  };
  Inner inner;
  int data[size]; // size is not declared in Outer, hence compiler give an error 
};
```

How can i do something like this?

Comment: You can't access non-static member variables of your own class like that anyway. Perhaps what you need is a `std::vector` instead, whose size could be set at run-time (when you actually have an initialized `Inner` object)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In another class I create an object from Outer struct, in constructor of that class. I want to make it simple as possible as i can for some reason, but I guess i should use vector and then resize it.

Comment: there is no such thing as variable sized array in C++ syntax and in C it's supported only for automatic storage (i.e. local variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `inner` is defined before `data`, initialization works just fine:

```
struct Outer
{
  struct Inner
  {
    int size{};
    int something_else{};
  };
  Inner inner;
  std::vector<int> data;
  Outer() : Inner(), data(inner.size) { }
};
```

Yes, a `struct` can have a constructor too. It's just a by-default-public class.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        int m_size{};
        int something_else{};
        Inner(int size) :m_size(size)
        {
        }
    };
    Inner inner{ 5 };
    int* data = new int[inner.m_size];
};


int main()
{
    Outer outer;
    for (int i = 0; i < outer.inner.m_size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << outer.data[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You should not make size variable public because after object is created, change in size variable will not change the size of array.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `new int[]` , prefer `std::vector<int>`. Currently this code has a memory leak.

Comment: ~Outer()
 {
  delete[] data;
 }

Comment: That's a nice way to do it, but the problem is `int data[size]`, and for changed in size, we can declare them `const`.
Maybe I just get confused for this project and I should use `std::vector`.
Thanks.

Comment: @enumerator: That's one leak fixed, but now you broke the copy constructor. The big advantage of `std::vector` is that it already has all the right member functions, and C++ will automatically use those when you have a `vector` as a member.

Answer (score -1):

The variable `size` has not been declared you're trying to access a memory block that doesn't exist

Assuming your needs don't require precise size I suggest to consider the following options

**Declare a macro**

```
#DEFINE size n
```

where n = your preferred size

**Dynamic Memory Allocation**

```
Inner* inner= malloc(size * sizeof *inner); //Where size = your specified size
```

Comment: 1) Macros are frowned upon in c++, for good reasons. 2) You should not use `malloc` in C++. 3) This does not answer the question - which here is probably an XY problem and needs more information about the X, so cannot really be answered yet.

Comment: OP did not provide enough context what did you expect me to answer?

Comment: You are right, the question in its current state cannot be answered. Then simply don't ;-). You may either help the OP refine his question until his problem can be understood and solved, or just move on to another question.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want C-style programming in C++.
I wrote my problem, if it's not clear, be kind and suggest a solution.
For now I will user `std::vector` as @Someprogrammerdude suggested.

Comment: @spectras I do not have the privilege to leave comments as of now, and I just wanted to help a person in need but alright I guess I understand

Alireza.N No worries good luck

Comment: @Ammar You seem to be in the perfect state of mind, I am sure you will very soon have that privilege and many others. Good luck and see you soon on SO :-)

Comment: @spectras I appreciate the kind words thank you